# Not able to install Jenkins Plugin

Tags: selenium, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Getting below error message when we upgrade the Jenkins from 2.77 to 2.78
Upgrade to Jenkins 2.78 failed: Failed to download from 
http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/war/2.78/jenkins.war.

After click on retry button getting error message:

> Checking internet connectivity
>   Checking update center connectivity
>   java.net.HttpRetryException: Invalid response code (404) from URL:   https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json?uctest
>   at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.testConnection(UpdateCenter.java:1258)
>   at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.checkUpdateCenter(UpdateCenter.java:1053)
>   at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$ConnectionCheckJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1488)
>   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>   at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:110)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: are you able to access the site from Jenkins machine? are you sure there ain't any proxy blocking the site.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, I never used Jenkin before and I am not accessing the site. I just want to configure the Maven with Janking and execute my test script on different machine

Comment: Can i know the details on which machine you are trying to do this. Windows or Linux

Comment: Window 7 Professional